# Wso2 API Manager 2.1.0 - API Store TAGS disappeared when tag name is "xxxx-group"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have upgraded to wso2 API Manger 2.1.0 version recently. After upgrade TAGS names with xxxx-group (grouping API) disappeared from API Store. For example When i put TAG name as **Pizza-group it does not appears on API Store** where as when i put tag name as just Pizza then it appears on API Store.

As per the documentation here "[Categorising and grouping APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customizing+the+API+Store)", on publisher we must add tags to APIs with the suffix "-group" to APIs (e.g., Workflow APIs-group, Integration APIs-group, Quote APIs-group.)

What could be issue here, please advise.

Comment: Are you getting this for all the APIs? Can you try adding a new API with a group?

Comment: Yes, it is an issue with new API also, to test this i have just now created a sample api and given tag as abc-group and published. API appeared on API Store and group name in right side but in TAGS it was nothing...

Comment: Let me explain you the behaviour first. If you haven't enabled tag-wise grouping once you add a tag as 'test-group' you will see the test-group tag in the store  tags. But if you enable tag-wise grouping, that tag will not be displayed under tags in store.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right on the behaviour . it is something new in 2.1.0 version of api manager.? in 2.0.0 it was showing both places. it there a way to change this ?

Comment: Actually, showing the group names when tag-wise grouping is enabled is a bug in APIM 2.0.0 and it is fixed in 2.1.0 - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5420. Stackoverflow reference - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39914749/3176125

Comment: Thank you. @Pubci i see it is being fixed in 2.1.0 we saw that and we were able to tweak following file to bring back the tags as it was needed by our team: /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/tag/tag-cloud/template.jag.